# Converting a javascript map code to React

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, jsx

I am new to React JS. I have the below code to generate a map using JAvascript.

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map" style="height:800px;"></div>
<script>
      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 33.847862, lng: -84.363433};

        var locations = [
          //list of locations
        ];
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;

        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: myLatLng,
          scrollwheel: true,
          zoom: 10
        });

        var icon = "img/store_marker.png"

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: icon
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent("<h3>"+locations[i][0]+ "</h3><br/>"+locations[i][4]+", <br/>"+locations[i][5]+", <br/>"+locations[i][6]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZqPocCNt5mdLvKi5fm72jq6e9on_IoaM&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to use this code to generate a map using React JS. I wrote the below code but I don't see anything being rendered on the screen. Below is my App.jsx.

```
import React from 'react';

import GoogleMap from 'google-map-react';
import MyGreatPlace from './my_great_place.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

     initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 33.847862, lng: -84.363433};

        var locations = [
          //list of locations
        ];
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker, i;

        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: myLatLng,
          scrollwheel: true,
          zoom: 10
        });

        var icon = "img/store_marker.png"

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: icon
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent("<h3>"+locations[i][0]+ "</h3><br/>"+locations[i][4]+", <br/>"+locations[i][5]+", <br/>"+locations[i][6]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
      }

    render() {

        initMap();

        return (
            <div id="map" style="height:800px;"></div>
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
}

App.defaultProps = {
    center: [33.847862, -84.363433],
    zoom: 10,
    scrollwheel: true
}


export default App;
```

Below is my index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

   <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React App</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZqPocCNt5mdLvKi5fm72jq6e9on_IoaM" async defer></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

I removed the "&callback=initMap" which is there in the JS html url as there is no such call back in React JS. Can someone please assist with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any place where you call React to render the component, there should be a:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Foo/>,
document.getElementById('bar')
);
```

Somewhere in the code, if you want React to render to the screen.

Have a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html

and: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the following problems with your code:

1. As Petter says you should use ReactDOM.render to render your component.
2. Your component is returning a div which is empty actually. If you want the initMap to be included inside your div then you should include it like this:

`<div id="map"> {this.initMap()} </div>`

3. You should also change your syntax as far as styling to something like this (if you ensist on instyle):

`<div id="map" style={{height:'800px'}}>
   {this.initMap()
</div>`

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

The browser wont know how to interpret your code before u compile ur code using babel and such.